# onClick action not working in Route in EmberJS

Tags: ember.js

I have a button which increase the value of quantity. i wrote the onclick action to increase the value of this quantity in the route.But this does not work, the onclick in not working and this does not give out a error as well.

i am new to EmberJS so please help.

This is the code which i tried.

My route.js

```
  actions: {
    increaseRequiredQuantity() {

        debugger;
        $('.qtyplus').click(function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();

            fieldName = $(this).attr('field');

            var currentVal = parseInt($(this.parentElement).find('input[name=' + fieldName + ']').val());
            var currentNewVal;

            if (!isNaN(currentVal)) {
                currentNewVal = currentVal + 1;
                $(this.parentElement).find('input[name=' + fieldName + ']').val(currentNewVal);
            } else {

                $(this.parentElement).find('input[name=' + fieldName + ']').val(0);
            }

        });
    }
}
```

this is how am calling the action from the template

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-number qtyplus" data-type="plus" field='quantity'{{action "increaseRequiredQuantity"}} id="btnIncrease"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span></button>
```

Comment: template hbs  actions bound to controller so either you should write it in controller, or use send method to call actions in route

Comment: i tried it writing in a controller too, but still the same result the onclick does not work and it does not give a error either :(

Comment: You may need to implement this in component when you do dom specific stuff.

Comment: Thank you for the replies. Will try and let you know:)

Answer (score 0):

The action should be in your controller. Here is a sample [twiddle](https://ember-twiddle.com/23c7b2b168c8ba485196aa6c330cbee3?openFiles=controllers.application.js%2C).

If you don't want to use the `controller`, have a look at [ember-route-action-helper](https://github.com/DockYard/ember-route-action-helper).

BTW, your action is modifing page with jquery. That is not the ember way of doing. You should pass the data to the components. Components should update the view.